# Python requests.get(): How to Print a Message if There is an Internet Connection Error?

Tags: python, python-requests, try-except

I am trying to print the error message: `Oops! Houston, we have a problem!` if for some reason there is any internet connection problem when trying to use `requests.get()`.

I have written the code below but it always prints `Oops! Houston, we have a problem!` even if there are no problems when trying to send the request.

```
try:
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    print("SUCCESS!")

except (requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects, requests.exceptions.RequestException, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError,):
    print("Oops! Houston, we have a problem!")
```

I would highly appreciate if you could give me some feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `requests.exceptions.RequestException` is catching all the responses, as it worked when I removed this from the `except`